# Drawing LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 onto a LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9

Tags: c++, 2d, directx, tiled

Is there are specific function in DirectX9 that allows you to specify where LPD3DXSPRITE blits the sprite? I'm trying to load a surface with tile information, and then display a portion of that surface to the backbuffer. I realized that with LPD3DXSPRITE::Draw() that there is no parameter for destination surface, it's probably automatically the backbuffer. Then my drawing of the gameworld surface covers the sprites.

Is there a solution, or a different way I have to approach this problem? I need the transparency which is why I thought of using the LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 object to handle my tile sprites, but the map won't fit on the backbuffer which is why I thought of loading the map onto a surface, and then drawing from that.

```
//Filename: MyDirectX.h
//Direct3D objects
extern LPDIRECT3D9 d3d; 
extern LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 d3ddev; 
extern LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 backbuffer;
extern LPD3DXSPRITE spriteobj;

LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 LoadTexture(string filename, D3DCOLOR transcolor = D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0,0,0));

void DrawTile(LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 source, int frame, int width, int height, int columns, LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 dest, int destx, int desty, D3DCOLOR color);
void BuildGameWorld();
void ScrollScreen();
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//Filename: MyGame.cpp
#include "MyDirectX.h"

//THIS FUNCTION HERE
void DrawTile(LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 source, int frame, int width, int height, int columns, LPDIRECT3DSURFACE9 dest, int destx, int desty, D3DCOLOR color)
{
    //get dimensions for the tile
    RECT r1;
    r1.left = (frame % columns) * width;
    r1.top = (frame / columns) * height;
    r1.right = r1.left + width;
    r1.bottom = r1.top + height;

    //can only draw to the backbuffer? Any work around?
    spriteobj->Draw(source, &r1, &D3DXVECTOR3(r1.right / 2, r1.bottom / 2, 0), &D3DXVECTOR3(destx, desty, 0), color);
}

void BuildGameWorld()
{
    int x, y;
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 tiles = nullptr;

    //load the texture file
    tiles = LoadTexture("goodly-2x.png", D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 255));

    spriteobj->Begin(D3DXSPRITE_ALPHABLEND);

    for(y = 0; y < MAPHEIGHT; y++)
    {
        for(x = 0; x < MAPWIDTH; x++)
        {
            DrawTile(tiles, MAP_LAYER1[y * MAPWIDTH + x], 32, 32, 16, gameworld, x * 32, y * 32, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255,255,255));
        }
    }

    spriteobj->End();

    //release the texture file
    tiles->Release();
}

//Without this function, and placing BuildGameWorld() inside the Game_Run()
//rendering phase the screen displays stripes of blue which I can only 
//assume is the transparent tiles working incorrectly*/
void ScrollScreen()
{
    //update horizontal scrolling position and speed
    ScrollX += SpeedX;
    if (ScrollX < 0) 
    {
        ScrollX = 0;
        SpeedX = 0;
    }
    else if (ScrollX > GAMEWORLDWIDTH - SCREENW)
    {
        ScrollX = GAMEWORLDWIDTH - SCREENW;
        SpeedX = 0;
    }

    //update vertical scrolling position and speed
    ScrollY += SpeedY;
    if (ScrollY < 0)
    {
        ScrollY = 0;
        SpeedY = 0;
    }
    else if (ScrollY > GAMEWORLDHEIGHT - SCREENH)
    {
        ScrollY = GAMEWORLDHEIGHT - SCREENH;
        SpeedY = 0;
    }

    //set dimensions of the source image
    RECT r1 = {ScrollX, ScrollY, ScrollX+SCREENW-1, 
        ScrollY+SCREENH-1};

    //set the destination rect
    RECT r2 = {0, 0, SCREENW-1, SCREENH-1};

    d3ddev->StretchRect(gameworld, &r1, backbuffer, &r2, 
        D3DTEXF_NONE);

}
```

Comment: Folks will always get criticized when they include no code, but you may have included too much. Its a huge help to answerers if you can express your code in a minimal example. I'm not sure who would be willing to look through all the code you've uploaded and try to identify the problem. Even if you left the big code block but pointed to the bit you are pretty sure is failing, it may get you more help and fewer downvotes.

Comment: I removed the extra code, and made a comment about the function I believe is causing the problem; ScrollScreen().

Comment: Thank you for the update. Good luck getting some help.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are starting with the legacy Direct3D 9 API using the deprecated D3DX helper library. Unless you have particularly outdated system requirements, a better solution would be to use DirectX 11, [DirectX Tool Kit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK), and the [SpriteBatch](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Sprites-and-textures) class.

Comment: I was using the API that "Beginning Game Programming" by Jonathan Harbour used, which was DirectX 9.0c I believe. I saw the Direct Input at the least was deprecated, and I couldn't get it to work properly, but I didn't know about D3DX. I'll take a look at the tool kit, and probably port my code over to DirectX 11.

So far I've only made Pong, and I'm working on a tile based game. Originally a platformer, but maybe going to do Breakout instead first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using ID3DXSprite, the easiest way to specify the render target would be using ID3DXRenderToSurface like this:

```
// inside IDirect3DDevice9::BeginScene() / EndScene() block
ID3DXRenderToSurface::BeginScene()
ID3DXSprite::Begin()

// draw your sprites

ID3DXSprite::End()
ID3DXRenderToSurface::EndScene()
```

Comment: Here are some helpful links:
http://www.gamedev.net/topic/491590-rendering-sprites-off-screen/
http://www.codesampler.com/dx9src/dx9src_7.htm

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't sure how to set the render target. My first run got it to work, minus the scrolling of the map. My runs after that are just a black screen still, but I'm going to continue working on it.

Comment: I couldn't get the ID3DXRenderToSurface way to work, but I saw that the Direct3D Device had a SetRenderTarget function. So my program runs like this:

    d3ddev->SetRenderTarget(NULL, gameworld);
    d3ddev->BeginScene();
    // Rendering Code in Here
    d3ddev->EndScene();
    d3ddev->SetRenderTarget(NULL, backbuffer);

Comment: ID3DXRenderToSurface  is actually a wrapper around SetRenderTarget.